# How extract the certain info from returned query information?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am attempting to connect to my locally hosted SQL server and query for a random name on the database table. This is not important as I am just getting started with SQL and JavaScript so I am attempting to start easy. However, after I query the server and the info returned and have it turned into a string and written to the locally hosted webpage using express I get

```json
{
  'recordsets': [[{'Name': 'Victor'}]],
  'recordset': [{'Name': 'Victor'}],
  'output': {},
  'rowsAffected': [1]
}
```

I would like to only get the name from this information. Is there a simple function like `results.Name` or something similar. I am using MySQL to host the server, and node.js to connect and query the server. I would like to point out the query and connection to the server is working properly and the local webpage on express is also working as expected. I want to get just the name from the query to have the ability to use logic later in the code depending on the name returned from the query.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var User_Selected = getRandomInt(1, 4);
  let connection = sql.connect(sqlConfig, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.write('DB Connected');
    }
    connection.query(
      'SELECT Name FROM customers where CustomerId =' + User_Selected,
      function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.end();
      });

  });

});
```

Comment: You've tagged both MySQL and SQL Server? Which is it?

Comment: Worse, you've posted images of text, which is **severly** frowned upon. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It would be MySQL. I did not realize both were separate platforms. I am just starting with SQL and learning on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're getting from the `connection.query` call is this:

```js
const result = {
  'recordsets': [[{'Name': 'Victor'}]],
  'recordset': [{'Name': 'Victor'}],
  'output': {},
  'rowsAffected': [1]
};
```

You are responding with the entirety of this result here:

```js
res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

If you want to respond with only the `Name` property, just replace that `res.write` with this:

```js
const name = result.recordset[0].Name;
res.write(name);
```